# Clang failing to find header files in non-standard location

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, header-files, compiler-flags

I am currently trying to build OpenPose. First, I will try to describe the environment and then the error emerging from it. Caffe, being built from source, resides in its entirety in [/Users...]/openpose/3rdparty instead of the usual location (I redact some parts of the filepaths in this post for privacy). All of its include files can be found in [/Users...]/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/include/caffe. After entering this command:

```
make -j`sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu` CXXFLAGS=-I[/Users/..]/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/include
```

This error followed:

```
[  0%] Building CXX object src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/core/arrayCpuGpu.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/face/faceExtractorCaffe.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/hand/handExtractorCaffe.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/bodyPartConnectorCaffe.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/maximumCaffe.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/netCaffe.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/netOpenCv.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/nmsCaffe.cpp.o
[/Users/..]/openpose/src/openpose/core/arrayCpuGpu.cpp:3:14: fatal error: 'caffe/blob.hpp' file not found
    #include <caffe/blob.hpp>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/core/arrayCpuGpu.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[/Users/etc..]/openpose/src/openpose/net/maximumCaffe.cpp:3:14: fatal error: 'caffe/blob.hpp' file not found
    #include <caffe/blob.hpp>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[/Users..]/openpose/src/openpose/net/nmsCaffe.cpp:3:14: fatal error: 'caffe/blob.hpp' file not found
    #include <caffe/blob.hpp>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[/Users..]/openpose/src/openpose/net/netCaffe.cpp:6:14: fatal error: 'caffe/net.hpp' file not found
    #include <caffe/net.hpp>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[/Users..]/openpose/src/openpose/net/netOpenCv.cpp:7:14: fatal error: 'caffe/net.hpp' file not found
    #include <caffe/net.hpp>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[/Users..]/openpose/src/openpose/net/bodyPartConnectorCaffe.cpp:3:14: fatal error: 'caffe/blob.hpp' file 1not error  generatedfound.

    #include <caffe/blob.hpp>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/maximumCaffe.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/nmsCaffe.cpp.o] Error 1
[/Users..]/openpose/src/openpose/face/faceExtractorCaffe.cpp:3:14: fatal error: 'caffe/blob.hpp' file not found
    #include <caffe/blob.hpp>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[/Users..]/openpose/src/openpose/hand/handExtractorCaffe.cpp:3:14: fatal error: 'caffe/blob.hpp' file not found
    #include <caffe/blob.hpp>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/netCaffe.cpp.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/bodyPartConnectorCaffe.cpp.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/netOpenCv.cpp.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/face/faceExtractorCaffe.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/hand/handExtractorCaffe.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why is clang failing to find blob.hpp and the other headers? I expected it to navigate to openpose/3rdparty/caffe/include, and then take it from there to find caffe/blob.hpp along with the other headers. I'm pretty new to make/c++ so I haven't tried many things other than adding the CXXFLAGS directly to the Makefile instead of passing it in through the terminal (didn't work).
Here is the Makefile: https://pastebin.com/yY7R9jVe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using cmake.  The makefiles generated by cmake don't conform to "standard" makefile conventions; in particular they don't use the `CXXFLAGS` variable.

When you're using cmake, you're not expected to modify the compiler options by changing the invocation of make.  Instead, you're expected to modify the compiler options by either editing the CMakeLists.txt file, or else by providing an overridden value to the `cmake` command line that is used to generate your makefiles.

Comment: Ok brilliant, everything built perfectly after I exported CXXFLAGS, recompiled with cmake, and then ran make again. Thanks!

Comment: Another `cmake` tip: you can add `VERBOSE=1` to the make command line (this one DOES go on the make command line!) to ask the makefile to show you all the compiler commands etc. instead of hiding them.  That can be useful to know whether, and in what order, the compiler is receiving options.